# How can I break an Azure DevOps pipeline if integration tests running inside of a container fail?

Tags: .net, docker, azure-pipelines, xunit, pact

I'm trying to create a build pipeline on Azure DevOps which is going to run a series of integration tests based on [Pact .Net](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net) inside of a Docker container.

How can I break this pipeline if any of these tests fail?

Note that the tests are being run inside of an XUnit project in my container.

Comment: Please add some more detail (e.g. code examples) so that more specific advice can be given. As it stands you're going to get a very generic response

Comment: How does your yaml file look like? And which task do you use to run the tests, vstest task or PS task?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the tests in Command-line with `dotnet test` or `vstest.console.exe` command, then we can add `failOnStderr: false` to break the pipeline if there's any error written to the StandardError stream.

```
container:
  image: xxx/xxx:xxx
  endpoint: 'xxx'

steps:
- script: |
    xxx
  failOnStderr: false

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      xxx
    failOnStderr: true
```